# how to trim video in laravel and get into blade

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, trim, laravel-8

so i am working on a project where a video uploading feature should be there,

this is how i uploading a video

//view for video

## video uploader

```
<form action="{{route('videoUploader')}}" role="form" id="postForm" name="postForm" method="POST" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ><br/>
    <input type="submit"  value="upload">
</form>
```

and on controller side the code is
//controller for video

```
public function videoUpload(Request $request){
        $files=$request->file('files');
        $videoArray=[];
        if($files){
            foreach($files as $video){
                $filename= $video->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $video->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore = $filename. '_'.time().'.'.$extension;
                $path = $video->move('storage/videos',$fileNameToStore);
                $videoArray[]=$fileNameToStore;
            }
            }
        return view('admin.Post.video',compact('videoArray'));
    }
```

and this is how i am getting and see output on blade

```
@if (!empty($videoArray))
@foreach ($videoArray as $video)
<iframe src="{{ asset('storage/videos/'.$video) }}"frameborder="0" width="250" height="200"  
allowfullscreen></iframe>
@endforeach
@endif
```

but the issue is, i want these videos to trim first, if video is more than 1 minute longer, it should be trimmed, and get trimmed video to show on the blade, and i don't have any idea how can i achieve this. i could not find any helpful tutorial on web for this, so i came here. please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First you have to upload the video and then you can get time and trim the video as per your need.

Use FFMpeg Pbmedia Laravel package for this. Open below link and add package into your laravel project

https://packagist.org/packages/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

Comment: i added and how can i use this, i asked recently please help there

Comment: Steps:
1. Install FFMPEG on your server.
2. Install FFMPEG laravel package from https://packagist.org/packages/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg

Above link includes all your problem solution.

Comment: thank you sir for reply again, i already did it but still facing some problem, explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087821/how-to-use-or-import-ffmpeg-in-a-laravel-controller

Answer (score 0):

with FFmpeg

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i input.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp4
```